# WPF Image fit to content inside a Canvas which is inside a Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, scrollviewer, wpf-grid

I have an implementation in which I'm having a scrollviewer in a UserControl.
Inside the scrollviewer I have a Grid which contains a canvas. Canvas in turn has an Image inside it. Something like this.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScrollViewer"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              MouseEnter="TargetImage_OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="TargetImage_OnMouseLeave" >

    <Grid x:Name="ImageGrid" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" ScaleX="{Binding ZoomScaleFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomScaleFactor}"  Changed="ScaleTransform_OnChanged"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>

        <Canvas Name="ImgCanvas">
            <Image Source="{Binding BmpImageSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="LoadedImage" 
                   MaxWidth="1920" MaxHeight="1080"
                   ClipToBounds="True" Style="{x:Null}"
                   Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

            </Image>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

What I want is when the Image is loaded it should fit to viewing area. I have tried several things to do this like setting the width of the Grid to its parent but apparently nothing has worked as I expect. Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Remove the Canvas. Note also that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Image.Source binding is pointless. It has no effect here.

Comment: Hi @Clemens, I tried removing the canvas but that makes the ScrollBar appear in the beginning itself. What I want is to fit the image in the viewing area without distorting the aspect ratio. On removing the canvas, the Strectch=Uniform property of Image doesn't seem to work.

Comment: May I ask why do you want a scrollviewer when the image will fit the viewing area?

Comment: ScrollViewer will be required to Pan the image when it will be zoomed as per my requirement.
What I wanted is to fit the image on load. That is I'm able to solve now by removing the canvas and setting the width of the grid to the parent UserControl's ActualWidth. However, I still want to know how can I do that without removing the canvas. :)

Comment: @Clemens Any way to do that keeping the canvas. The reason I'm keeping the canvas so that I can draw lines/shapes on top of the Image. I know this is possible in Grid also but perhaps Canvas is preferred for such things.

Comment: @Karan Kakwani did you found anyway to achieve this without removing the canvas?